# How to make a URL entered without protocol into an anchor absolute reference

Tags: html, href

I have a form where users can enter the URL for their website and I then provide a link to the website.  I'd like to allow the address to be entered without the protocol (eg `www.example.com` instead of `http://www.example.com`).

But if I don't include the protocol in the `<a>` href attribute the link is relative to my site and does not work.  I'm guessing that HTML5 rel="external" might help in future.

Is there a way to use `<a href="www.example.com">` so that it is treated as an absolute link reference?  I can assume http if no protocol is provided, but this also won't always work.

Comment: _“I can assume http if no protocol is provided, but this also won't always work”_ – well if you can not make that educated guess with certainty, then how do you expect anything else to make it?

Comment: you can regex test the urls for occurances of protocol name and if missing just append one...

Comment: I'm prepending http where the protocol is not given, but why should I have to do this?  If you type ``www.example.com`` into a browser address field you don't need to include the protocol.  I'd like to do the same with my link.  I was using a regular expression to require the protocol but the user could enter the wrong protocol.